# What is the proper regular expression for uid in base64 and token in Python?

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

In Django 2.0, I deal with uid and token for user email confirmation.

`'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
'token': PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user),`

My urlpatterns is like below, however pattern is not found:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/'
        '(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', confirm_user_email, name='confirm-user-email'),]
```

The error message is like this:

> Reverse for 'confirm-user-email' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'Mw', 'token': '4t9-a61218655569c14203b8'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['member\/confirm/(?P[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']

Comment: The regex looks ok to me. The reverse is failing because `uidb64` is bytes  `b'Mw'`.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks:) I've just solved it. And I will figure it out why it needs decode() in django 2.0.

Comment: My answer links to [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#removed-support-for-bytestrings-in-some-places) which explain why you need to `decode()` in Django 2.0.